# get all elements in source line lxml python

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, lxml

I'm extracting some html information and querying it using the `.xpath` method in python. For one particular application I would like to extract all elements belonging to a particular sourceline. For instance

```
with open(self.file_path, 'r') as f:
    page = f.read()
tree = html.fromstring(page)
all = tree.xpath(r'/html/body//a')
print(all[5].sourceline)
```

The above yields sourceline number 14, which contains the following source html.

```
26) <a name="l26" style="background-color: #ffffff">        subroutine </a><a style="background-color: #ffcccc">AdjustParticleDiscretisation()</a>
```

How do I then extract all the contents of this html  using the sourceline rather than the conventional xpath query? Or does xpath have some syntax that is sourceline aware?

Thanks

Comment: Note: shadowing builtin `all`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in getting the content visible on the page, you could use: `all[5].text`, as mentioned here: http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#text

If you need the actual html of that element you can use ElementTree's `tosstring` method:

`import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
etree.tostring(all[5])`

Also, as CristFati mentioned, try to avoid using `all` as a variable since it's a python built-in function and you have overwritten it's reference.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all